# Relation between arith.nl.rounds and final-checks

Tags: configuration, z3, usage-statistics

Is there any relation between the configuration option `smt.arith.nl.rounds` and the statistics value `final-checks` (or is it just a coincidence that the description of the former mentions "final checks")?

I ran Windows x64 builds of Z3 4.3.2 (official download) and of Z3 4.4 0ab54b9e0c33 on an SMTLIB program, and in both cases the reported number of `final-checks` (around 10,000) appears to be unaffected by whichever value I choose for `smt.arith.nl.rounds` (I tried 1, 64, 128, ..., 1024 and 4096).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All theories have final checks, but `smt.arith.nl.rounds` is only for the non-linear arithmetic solver (old; not NLSAT). There may be lots of final checks, none of which involve any non-linear arithmetic, or they use other methods to solve those parts.